# Losing files created by Google Drive app when access revoked and then granted

Tags: google-drive-api

My app wants access to files it creates only. When I revoke access by going to my google drive and "Manage apps", and then later re-grant credentials to the same app, I lose access to previously created files and they don't show up when listing files. This seems like a bad design decision, but perhaps it is a bug. Is it intentional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design, and is part of Google's dedication to putting the user's privacy first in Google Drive. When an app is uninstalled, all oauth tokens are revoked and the app loses the ability to open these files.

Sorry if this is a nuisance for you, but the alternative might be surprising for some users to find that an app still has access long after uninstalling and reinstalling.